# Can't pass images as params in Rspec Rails controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

Trying to test the create action in post_controller. All other controllers' create actions work just fine.

After some debugging, the error seems to be the params. The images passed from the post factory are blank in the controller

**post_spec.rb**

```
describe 'POST #create' do
    it 'check post creation' do
      new_post = build :post, user: user
      attrs = new_post.attributes
      attrs.store(:images, [ Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(image_url, 'image/jpg') ])
      post posts_path, params: { post: new_post.attributes }
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
end
```

**post.rb(model)**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many_attached :images

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 1000 }
  validates :images, presence: true, limit: { min: 1, max: 10 },
                     content_type: ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/webp']
end
```

**post.rb (factory)**

```
image_url = '/home/dev/Downloads/a1.jpg'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    title { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    images { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(image_url, 'image/jpg') }
    user
  end
end
```

**post_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :user_id, images: [])
end
```

When check for errors on @post here' the output

```
['Images cannot be blank']
```

new_post in post_spec

```
#<Post id: nil, title: "Sequi excepturi quam quos.", user_id: 307, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

new_post.attributes in post_spec

```
{"id"=>nil, "title"=>"Sequi excepturi quam quos.", "user_id"=>307, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your

**post_controller.rb**

```rb
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :user_id, images: [])
end
```

you are requiring an array of images, but in test you pass single instance of image.

Either edit your `params.require` in controller or update your factory (post) file, what suits better.

So now if you change your factory code to
**post.rb (factory)**

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    title { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    images { [Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('/home/dev/Downloads/a1.jpg', 'image/jpg')] }
    user
  end
end
```

You will have your images filled.